# 404 image not found with docker & ngnix

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

i'm creating a local wordpress site with docker & ngnix.
Everything works, but i have a problem with the images.
i try to upload on my admin WP and the result is this
[image: WP admin media section]

when i try to view the image i have this result

[image: NOT found 404]

my docker-compose.yml file below

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    build: ./docker/php
    volumes:
      - "$PWD/wp-content:/var/www/wp-content"
      - "$PWD/wp-config.local.php:/var/www/wp-config.php"
    depends_on: 
      - mariadb
  mariadb:
    build: ./docker/mariadb
    restart: "on-failure"
    environment:
      #MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pass"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "wordpress"
      MYSQL_USER: "user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "pass"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pass"
    volumes:
      - "$PWD/docker/mariadb/dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
  nginx:
    build: ./docker/nginx
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    links:
      - php
    volumes: 
      - "$PWD/wp-content:/var/www/wp-content"
      - "$PWD/wp-config.local.php:/var/www/wp-config.php"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:5.1.0
    ports:
      - "8800:80"
    depends_on: 
      - mariadb
    environment: 
      PMA_HOST: "mariadb"
      PMA_USER: "pass"
      PMA_PASSWORD: "pass"
```

Comment: Any luck so far? I'm having the same issue. Thanks